# Probes in K8's failed with 404

Tags: kubernetes, akka-http

I'm running an **akkaHttp** application in a **Deployment** the pod created and running successfully and in a ready state but when in the deployment I added **livenessProbe**, **readinessProbe** and **startupProbe** the app is in **running** state but not in a **ready** state, After describing the pod I saw an error `Startup probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 404`, `Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 404` `Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 404`. I increase the initial delay as well but still getting same problem.

here are my yaml files:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: akka-deployment

spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: akka-label
  template:
    metadata:
      name: akka-pod
      labels:
        app: akka-label
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: akka-container
          image: elasticdeployment:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8083
              name: elastic-port
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: 8083
            initialDelaySeconds: 50
            periodSeconds: 10
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: 8083
            initialDelaySeconds: 50
            periodSeconds: 10
          startupProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: 8083
            failureThreshold: 30
            periodSeconds: 10
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: akka-service

spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: akka-label
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8083
```

Where I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your probes are hitting `/` on port `8083` and that is returning a `404`. You can check this by port-forwarding into the pod. Since you only have one replica, you can do it this way:

```
kubectl port-forward -n {namespace} deployment/akka-deployment 8083:8083
```

Then in another terminal:

```
curl -I localhost:8083/
```

This curl replicates what the probes are trying to do. Unless the probe check succeeds (i.e. returns `200`), your pod will never be ready.

In fact, since you have also set this for the liveness probe, the cluster will start killing your pod since it thinks its dead.

You should investigate why the container is returning `404`. Maybe you're pinging the wrong port, or maybe you need to use a different path to check (perhaps `/health` or `/status`?)